# How do I kill 'repo sync' using crontab given it spawns many processes?

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill, synchronization

I need to 'repo sync' the Android source overnight, as my monthly bandwidth is limited.

, I start the 'repo sync' at midnight, then want to kill it at 8am. The following is the command:

```
2 0 * * * /home/user/android-src/reposync.sh
```

reposync.sh contains:

```
cd /home/user/android-src
/home/user/bin/repo sync
```

I was hoping to kill it with the following cron entries:

```
55 7 * * * ps -eo pid,args | grep repo | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} kill {}
0 8 * * * ps -eo pid,args | grep repo | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} kill -9 {}
```

The problem is that 'repo sync' spawns many processes - lots of 'git', 'curl', 'git-remote-http', 'python', (and I think a 'bash' and an 'sh', as I put the repo sync command into a .sh script). (Apologies for my ignorance/terminology.)

How can I find the processes to kill them? Or is there a better way? Will repo run as a normal user and I can just kill all that user's tasks? I'd like to leave my computer running over a few days unattended, and have it connect up every night and disconnect every morning, although any solutions gratefully considered, including the ugly, e.g., should I kill the internet connection so repo times out then resume it? There is nothing else running on the server, (VirtualBox on Win7 x64 running Ubuntu 10.04), so should I just reboot every 8am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative argument to `kill` to kill the entire process group.

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -eo pid,args |
awk '/[r]epo/{print $1}' |
xargs -I {} kill "$@" -{}
```

Note also the ancient FAQ about how to avoid the [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) `grep | grep -v grep | awk`.

Invoke this like

```
55 7 * * * /path/to/killsync
0 8 * * * /path/to/killsync -9
```

We hope the second one will never actually be needed; that's hopefully [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#kill) too.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000538/linux-kill-with-negative-pid

Comment: I'm getting ERROR: unknown signal name "13738". It is the correct PID. Unfortunately I'm out of my depth trying to figure out what the kill parameter "$@" is or does.

Comment: In a shell script, `"$@"` expands to a properly quoted list of the script's arguments.  So if you say `killsync -s 9` then `"$@"` will be `-s 9` inside the script.

Comment: Does the `kill` documentation on your system mention the negative PID convention?  Maybe as a workaround, always pass in an explicit signal number, i.e. run the first script as `killsync -15`.

Comment: You're right triplee thanks, my kill docs don't mention negative PID (updated Ubuntu 12.04). Will sending -15 kill the rest of the process group too?

Comment: (Unfortunately I needed to set this up within 2 hours of posting the question, so I used shutdown -r. Pursuing this in case any future visitors have a similar requirement. Huge thanks to everyone.)

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/kill.1.html does document this behavior.

Comment: 15 is the default signal for `kill`; so `kill -15 -1234` should send signal 15 to all processes in the same process group as process 1234. Whether they will actually die from that depends on the individual applications.

Comment: Sorry yes the negative PID is mentioned in `man kill`. Sending `-15` is the answer. If I send `kill -1234`, I get the error "invalid signal specification". If I specify `kill -15 -1234` the group is terminated. Huge thanks for your persistence and patience.

Comment: If this helped solve your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Thanks!

Comment: Oops very sorry, done.

Answer (score 0):

The process you need to kill has spawned child processes that need to be killed also:

```
vi killemall.sh
---------------
#!/bin/bash
# 
# Get the process PID
# Kill all the processes that have a parent pid = PID
# Kill the master process
#
MASTERPID=`ps -eo pid,args | grep repo | awk '{print $1}'`
ps -ef | grep ${MASTERPID} | awk '{print $1}'` | while read PIDX; do kill -9 ${PIDX} 2>/dev/null; done;
```

Will repo run as a normal user and I can just kill all that user's tasks?

```
# Should work, but it's a complete overkill
```

should I kill the internet connection so repo times out then resume it? 
so should I just reboot every 8am?

```
# No need to come up with "excentric" solutions. Follow the Kill-Em-ALL approach, and that should solve your issue.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, perhaps because the MASTERPID=`ps..` command returns two PIDs. One is the repo process, a python command, and I assume the other PID is that of the MASTERPID=`ps..` command itself, as I can't find the PID when I look at ps aux, and it seems it'd catch its own arg. How can I exclude its own process, (if my diagnosis is correct)?

Comment: I was wrong, the second process is `grep --color=auto repo`. So I tried: `MASTERPID=``ps -eo pid,args | grep repo | grep -v color=auto | awk '{print $1}'```
`ps -ef | grep ${MASTERPID} | awk '{print $1}'` | while read PIDX; do kill -9 ${PIDX} 2>/dev/null; done;`
But nothing dies.

Comment: Sorry for the punctuation - editing forbidden. I tried adding 'grep -v color=auto' which does then return only one PID, but it isn't killed.

Comment: Just noticed the WHILE loop in your 2nd line. Great thing to learn, and means my above comments are utterly irrelevant.